# Anaconda: No module named Scientific

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

I use Anaconda Python. In order to plot band structures, I followed the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
adapted from https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/dacapo/Examples#calculating-a-band-diagram
'''
from ase import *
from ase.calculators.jacapo import *

b = 3.61/2.
bulk = Atoms([Atom('Cu',(0,0,0))],
             cell=[[0,b,b],
                   [b,0,b],
                   [b,b,0]])

calc = Jacapo('2.5.1-Cu.nc',
              pw=340,
              nbands=8,
              symmetry=True,
              kpts=(10,10,10),debug=100)

bulk.set_calculator(calc)

# run the calculation
energy = calc.get_potential_energy()
```

at the following link:

[Plotting band Strucures](http://gilgamesh.cheme.cmu.edu/doc/software/jacapo/2-bulk/2.5-band-structure/2.5.0-band-structure.html)

I installed [Atomic Simulation Environment](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/about.html) (ASE) module. But when I run it, the error comes saying that module named Scientific is absent.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ase.calculators.jacapo import *
  File "/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ase/calculators/jacapo/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Scientific
ImportError: No module named Scientific
```

If it helps, the `__init__.py` file at `/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ase/calculators/jacapo/` reads as:

```
import Scientific
assert [int(x) for x in Scientific.__version__.split('.')] >= [2, 8]
from ase.calculators.jacapo.jacapo import *
```

I have been trying to locate the true Scientific package and install it, but all in vain. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to install Scientific python, it does not come with ASE, as it may only be a dependency of certain calculators.
[Here is a link to Scientific python's installation page.](http://dirac.cnrs-orleans.fr/plone/software/scientificpython/installation-instructions/)